# Changing the style or value for .val() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Here is my jQuery code:

```
            if(data.status == 'Waved')
            {
                $("#wave"+data.id).val("Unwave");
            }
            else if(data.status == 'Unwaved')
            {
                $("#wave"+data.id).val("Wave");
            }
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<input type="button" style="width:50px" id="wave_id" value="Wave" data-action="button">
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
if(result == 'Waved')
        {
                    $("#wave"+link_id).val("Unwave");
        }
        else
        {
                    $("#wave"+link_id).val('Waved');
        }
```

Here is my question, how do I change the "width" in style here: style="width:50px" to be something like width:60px when it shows "Unwave"?

Currently the width of the button is 50px for both "Wave" and "Unwave". How can I make it so that the width stays 50px for "Wave" and changes to 60px when it changes to "Unwave"?

Comment: is your PHP code really a php code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change width when value is "Unwave"

```
$("#wave"+link_id).val("Unwave").css('width','60px');
```

Comment: That works but I am using AJAX - no refresh so it needs to change the style without refreshing the page.

Comment: So extend the condition in your ajax response

Answer (score 1):

Just add `.css('width','60px')`

```js
if (data.status == 'Waved') {
  $("#wave" + data.id).val("Unwave").css('width', '50px');

} else if (data.status == 'Unwaved') {
  $("#wave" + data.id).val("Wave").css('width', '60px');
}
```

```html
<input type="button" style="width:50px" id="wave_id" value="Wave" data-action="button">
```

Comment: That works but I am using AJAX - no refresh so it needs to change the style without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
$("#wave"+link_id).css("width", "60px");
```

so it can be like this:

```
if(result == 'Waved')
{
  $("#wave"+link_id).val("Unwave");
  $("#wave"+link_id).css("width", "60px");
}
else
{
  $("#wave"+link_id).val('Waved');
  $("#wave"+link_id).css("width", "50px");
}
```

or simply like this:

```
if(result == 'Waved')
    {
      $("#wave"+link_id).val("Unwave").css("width", "60px");
    }
    else
    {
      $("#wave"+link_id).val('Waved').css("width", "50px");
    }



if(data.status == 'Waved')
        {
            $("#wave"+data.id).val("Unwave").css("width", "60px");
        }
        else if(data.status == 'Unwaved')
        {
            $("#wave"+data.id).val("Wave").css("width", "50px");
        }
```

Comment: That works but I am using AJAX - no refresh so it needs to change the style without refreshing the page.

Comment: Use this in your AJAX call where you change the text

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (data.status == 'Waved')
    {
       $("#wave"+link_id).val("Unwave").css("width", "50px");
    }
    else
    {
       $("#wave"+link_id).val('Waved').css("width", "60px");
    }
```

Comment: That works but I am using AJAX - no refresh so it needs to change the style without refreshing the page.